# QT HTTP GET , What's wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, get, qthttp

This is the code :

```
QEventLoop eventLoop;
QNetworkAccessManager mgr();
QObject::connect(mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
QUrl url(site);
QNetworkRequest req(url);
QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.get(req);
eventLoop.exec();

if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
    cout << "Success" endl;
    delete reply;
}
else {
    cout << "Failure" endl;
    delete reply;
}
```

Errors found:

> .. \ request.cpp (17): error C2665: 'QObject ::
>   connect': none of 3 overload could convert all kinds of topics

and

> .. \ request.cpp (20): error C2228: the element to the
>   left of '.get' must be a class, structure or union

Answer (score 3):

This is called [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), the compiler thinks that `mgr` is a function declaration. To fix this, just change

```
QNetworkAccessManager mgr();
```

to

```
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
```

You also have an error in your `connect`, it should look like this (notice the `&` before `mgr`, since `connect` expects pointers):

```
QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra brackets. Use:

```
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
```

`QNetworkAccessManager` does not have constructor without arguments, so parser understands it like function declaration.
Also you probably get warning in second line, like:

```
: warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
QNetworkAccessManager mgr();
                         ^~
```